# sql server query with a too "ORs" clauses

Tags: sql-server

I have a dictionary container with next info:

```
{ID=412, CATEG=1}, 
{ID=413, CATEG=2}, 
{ID=414, CATEG=3}, 
{ID=415, CATEG=4}
```

I need to construct a string query for execute it in SQL SERVER, something like that:

```
select * from PASSAGES psg 
where   (psg.ID = 413 AND psg.CATEGORY_ID = 2)
                OR  (psg.ID = 414 AND psg.CATEGORY_ID = 3)
                OR  (psg.ID = 415 AND psg.CATEGORY_ID = 4)
                OR  (psg.ID = 416 AND psg.CATEGORY_ID = 5)
```

The problem is that my container now have 4 elements, if it would have 200 i would have 200 ORs ??

Any idea about avoid too many ORs ?  (I need a string query, i can not use a stored procedure)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `join` instead, putting the values in a derived table:

```
select p.*
from passages p join
     (values (413, 2), (414, 3), (415, 4), (416, 5)
     ) v(id, category_id)
     on p.id = v.id and p.category_id = v.category_id;
```

Comment: Man, you're a wizard.  I was working up some awkward idea about creating a user-defined table type.

Answer (score 0):

If you can store that dictionary container in a table it will be easier to use it in an (IN) clause like this:

```
SELECT * FROM PASSAGES AS psg
JOIN Dictionary AS D ON psg.ID = D.ID
WHERE psg.ID IN (D.ID) AND psg.CATEGORY_ID IN (D.CATEG)
```

and as the Dictionary table records increase the query will be fixed all time without multiple (ORs).